# Error with NIO while trying to copy large file

Tags: java, nio

I have the code to copy a file to another location.

```
public static void copyFile(String sourceDest, String newDest) throws IOException {

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceDest);
    File destFile = new File(newDest);
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }

}
}
```

While copying small chunks, say, 300-400 Mb, everything works like magic. But when I tried to copy a file a size of 1.5 Gb it failed. The stack is:

> run:
>   12.01.2011 11:16:36 FileCopier main
>   SEVERE: Exception occured while copying file. Try again.
>   java.io.IOException: Map failed
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:748)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromFileChannel(FileChannelImpl.java:527)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(FileChannelImpl.java:590)
>           at FileCopier.copyFile(FileCopier.java:64)
>           at FileCopier.main(FileCopier.java:27)
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:745)
>           ... 4 more
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

I haven't worked with NIO closely. Could you please help me out? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have a try with Files.copy http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html if it works have a look-see in the src

Comment: Thank you. But I'd rather not use third party libraries in this specific case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have been hit by an [old bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4469299) which already encountered some time ago. I was not trying to copy a file but rather to seek through an memory-mapped file which failed as well. For me the workaround is to seek through the file in a loop and request the [GC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()) and [finalizers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalization()) to run every now and then.

The memory-mapped `ByteBuffers` release their mapping in the finalizer and make room for new mappings. This is very ugly, but at least it works. Let's hope they did something about this in the coming NIO iteration.

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you for the insight. http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4946

Comment: Yes, Actually they have resolved the bug in JRE 1.7 (I checked in 1.7.0_51)

Answer (score 2):

You are memory mapping a file but there is limited memory address space in a 32-bit JVM (which I presume you are using) so the map method is failing. I don't think you can map more than 1.3-1.4 GB of disk data. What heap size are you using?

You can try reducing your heap size or use a 64-bit JRE. Alternatively, don't read the file by mapping it to memory using NIO. Instead, use the traditional way of a buffered reader and writer to read and write data from one file to the other.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to stick to NIO, just using iterative approach with a buffer a size of 64 Mb.