# To copy zip file into another zipfile

Tags: java

Currently I am using below code to copy zip inside another zip.But when zip file size increases eg:2GB, program is throwing out of memory error.I have increased xmx to 1024, still prfoblem is same.Is thr s any alternate method to handle large files ?

```
public static void zipFile(File srcFile, File zipFile)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedInputStream origin = null;
        FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
        // out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED);
        byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
        origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName());
        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        int count;
        while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
            out.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        origin.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please wrap your code in code tags? Select all of your code and press CTRL+K

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `FileChannel.transferTo` method? It's more efficient. Since this is done at OS level, I'm assuming it shouldn't depend on Java Heap size.

If that fails too take a look at this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666616/problem-with-nio-whily-trying-to-copy-large-file).

Answer (score 1):

You are only copying bytes when you come right down to it. You don't need to process either file as a Zip file. Just copy the bytes.